# How do I translate British English strings into US English?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have created my own custom module. All of my outputted strings are wrapped in t functions. I have enabled Locale in core. I need to alter some of my module's strings and some field labels too, slightly, just a word here and there, form British English into US English.

What I'm trying to acheive is: if my site is being viewed in the US I want that to be automatically detected, and the adjusted strings/field labels displayed.

Thanks.

**Solution:** Install `ip2country` module. This provides a function called `ip2country_get_country` which returns an ISO 3166 two-character country code based on the user's IP address. Create a helper function that returns a boolean TRUE/FALSE is the country code is 'US'. Then just use if-else constructs to translate the required text.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure about what this means "I cannot see any of the strings from my custom module." ... so my answer here may not be useful.  but here goes:

Machines don't care about what the similarities are, variations of english might as well be chinese and spanish.. which works in our favour here!

Assuming (US) english is your primary/default language,  translate only the strings you want in to the Queen's English:  admin/config/regional/translate/translate

You may have to do some interesting stuff to make detection/selection work,  but I think that's a new question.

Comment: When I navigate to admin/config/regional/translate/translate the filters are: Language: All | Search in: Both | Limit to: All. Only approx. 30 strings are listed. The first is: 'An AJAX HTTP error occurred.' from the text group 'Built-in interface'. Should I be seeing many more? The language is set to: English (built-in). Is that US English? Thanks.

Comment: the default is "english", afaik there's no "US English" or "British English".. that's where your detection will ahve to get interesting.

I would suggest reading up on "localizing drupal"... treat it all as you might for a new language,  but only translate those strings you need to translate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two modules that may help you:

[stringoverrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)

or

[stringoverrides_advanced](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides_advanced)